# Adding new Roles into .NET Core Web API Authorisation without Code Change

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I am trying to implement a role based authorization in my web API's and Azure Functions. So there are certain roles and corresponding AD groups looking something like this

```
Role                    AD Group
-----------------------------------

myapp.data.ro            GBL ROL IT myapp data RO
myapp.data.rw            GBL ROL IT myapp data write
myapp.logs.read          GBL ROL IT myapp logs read
myapp.file.read          GBL ROL IT myapp file read
myapp.contributor.all    GBL ROL IT myapp admin
------------------------------------
```

So I have implemented authorization using Authorize attribute at various controller level.

But the challenge is when the requirement changed and I need to create teams level roles.

So it would be like

myapp.team1.data.ro or myapp.team2.data.ro or myapp.team2.file.read like that

So how can I handle this situation and when a new team comes how can I onboard that teams into the authorization without any code change?

Ultimately my requirement is to filter the data for different teams and at different levels like file,data,logs etc.

I have got a suggestion to use some middleware to manage the roles. But again that requires code change when new roles added, isnt it?

I thought about to have ROLES in DB and the middleware checks the request roles against that ROLES MAPPING and respond with success or forbidden (403)

Please share a good approach than this. I am a very beginner with these AD groups and roles thing in Azure.

Or is there is any service in Azure itself for the dynamic Role management and authorization

Answer (score 0):

I think first you have to be sure about what is storing the role information in your deployment, and what is going to handle modifying this information.

It seems like you're using Active Directory for STORING this information.

Now, what is handling modifications? Like, who/what initially creates those Active Directory groups you already have? And what kind of event would trigger changes (how do you/someone else knows to add a new group to AD, or rather how do you/someone else knows there's a new team?).

If these groups are created for you - there's nothing else needed. When a new group is added to AD the application is going to work just fine with it (with certain caveats, like propagation time and limited OU scopes for the service account/credntials used by your service itself).

If you have to create these groups yourself... there are many ways, you need to decide how and what works best for you/your stack. Microsoft documentation has details on creating groups in Azure Active Directory (I assume that's what you're using, for self-hosted/on-prem Active Directory it might be slightly different): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/groups-create-eligible

You can call a PowerShell script, make a web request from your C# application, or trigger an Azure Function that does it. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a NuGet package with library for interacting/adding groups to Azure AD as well. There are many options.